# SELECT or INSERT a row in one command

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.0 and I have a table with just an artificial key (auto-incrementing sequence) and another unique key. (Yes, there is a reason for this table. :)) I want to look up an ID by the other key or, if it doesn't exist, insert it:

```
SELECT id
FROM mytable
WHERE other_key = 'SOMETHING'
```

Then, if no match:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (other_key)
VALUES ('SOMETHING')
RETURNING id
```

The question: is it possible to save a round-trip to the DB by doing both of these in one statement? I can insert the row if it doesn't exist like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (other_key)
SELECT 'SOMETHING'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE other_key = 'SOMETHING')
RETURNING id
```

... but that doesn't give the ID of an existing row. Any ideas? There is a unique constraint on other_key, if that helps.

Comment: It's sad that you had so say "there's a reason for this table" to have  both a auto-incrementing key AND a unique key.  If at all possible, one should ALWAYS have a unique and not null key if using auto-incrementing surrogate keys.  Otherwise, there is *nothing* preventing duplicate real information.  I'm not saying that surrogate keys don't have their uses, but the pervading idea that having both is somehow wrong is a data quality disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Related answer dealing with possible race conditions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Have you tried to union it?

---

Edit - this requires Postgres 9.1:

```
create table mytable (id serial primary key, other_key varchar not null unique);

WITH new_row AS (
INSERT INTO mytable (other_key)
SELECT 'SOMETHING'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE other_key = 'SOMETHING')
RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM new_row
UNION
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE other_key = 'SOMETHING';
```

results in:

```
 id | other_key 
----+-----------
  1 | SOMETHING
(1 row)
```

Comment: I suspect it'll work in postgres 9.1. At the very worse, 9.1 will allow to write: `with new_row as (insert ... returning *) select * from new_row ... union select * from ...`

Comment: Interesting, +1. I'll keep this in mind for the future when we upgrade to 9.1.

Comment: @EMP: I agree, fascinating to see this ability; then again, I'm looking forward to writable CTEs in general

Comment: You can also make `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE other_key = 'SOMETHING'` a CTE since you use it twice.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale I've recently seen that, and the example I saw used a `UNION ALL`, which I'm not quite sure why, other than I think it yields performance.  `UNION` and `UNION ALL` should both only return one record.

Comment: How about performance? This approach requires two index lookups (one for INSERT, another for SELECT).

Comment: @vol7ron, UNION ALL does not eliminate duplicates, in case INSERT worked, you will get two rows, unless you use LIMIT 1.

Comment: @greatvovan: there are better ways to do this now (see Aloyse's answer).

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy I saw it, but I doubt it is better. It does only one lookup (in theory), but UPDATE may require DB engine to move row tuple in the table which involves additional read-write IO as well as index update. It requires load test on big number of rows to find out what it better.

Comment: @greatvovan: You're most welcome to post your findings in an answer. I haven't touched Postgres in years, so I'm probably no longer the right person to ask how the performance differs between the old and the new approaches. I would point out, though, that intuitively Aloyee's approach can be improved with an in-memory table (such as an additional `with` statement), so that only has one index lookup occurs (to check whether the record exists). I'm not seeing any obvious good reason to store `existed` in a table.

Answer (score 3):

using 9.5 i successfully tried this

- based on Denis de Bernardy's answer
- only 1 parameter
- no union
- no stored procedure
- atomic, thus no concurrency problems (i think...)

*The Query:*

```
WITH neworexisting AS (
    INSERT INTO mytable(other_key) VALUES('hello 2') 
    ON CONFLICT(other_key) DO UPDATE SET existed=true -- need some update to return sth
    RETURNING * 
)
SELECT * FROM neworexisting
```

first call:

```
id|other_key|created            |existed|
--|---------|-------------------|-------|
 6|hello 1  |2019-09-11 11:39:29|false  |
```

second call:

```
id|other_key|created            |existed|
--|---------|-------------------|-------|
 6|hello 1  |2019-09-11 11:39:29|true   |
```

*First create your table ;-)*

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    other_key text NOT NULL,
    created timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    existed bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT mytable_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT mytable_uniq UNIQUE (other_key) --needed for on conflict
);
```

Comment: Does this not lock the row for writing unnecessarily? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/4871468

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no special SQL syntax that allows you to do select or insert.  You can do what Ilia mentions and create a sproc, which means it will not do a round trip fromt he client to server, but it will still result in two queries (three actually, if you count the sproc itself).

Comment: @GiovanniP - no, Denis's answer only works in 9.1, not 9.0 and in any event I read the question as wanting a special sql statement to do this.

Comment: @TruongSinh - sometimes the answer to a yes or no question is no.  They can't always be constructive.  In this case, the answer is no in regards to version 9.0.  So I fail to understand your motivation for downvoting an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a stored procedure

```
IF (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE other_key = 'SOMETHING' LIMIT 1) < 0 THEN
 INSERT INTO mytable (other_key) VALUES ('SOMETHING')
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative to Denis answer, that I think is less database-intensive, although a bit more complex:

```sql
create table mytable (id serial primary key, other_key varchar not null unique);
```

```sql
WITH table_sel AS (
    SELECT id
    FROM mytable
    WHERE other_key = 'test'
    UNION
    SELECT NULL AS id
    ORDER BY id NULLS LAST
    LIMIT 1
), table_ins AS (
    INSERT INTO mytable (id, other_key)
    SELECT
        COALESCE(id, NEXTVAL('mytable_id_seq'::REGCLASS)),
               'test'
    FROM table_sel
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING id
)
SELECT * FROM table_ins
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table_sel
WHERE id IS NOT NULL;
```

In `table_sel` CTE I'm looking for the right row. If I don't find it, I assure that `table_sel` returns at least one row, with a union with a `SELECT NULL`.

In `table_ins` CTE I try to insert the same row I was looking for earlier. `COALESCE(id, NEXTVAL('mytable_id_seq'::REGCLASS))` is saying: `id` could be defined, if so, use it; whereas if `id` is null, increment the sequence on `id` and use this new value to insert a row. The `ON CONFLICT` clause assure
that if `id` is already in `mytable` I don't insert anything.

At the end I put everything together with a `UNION` between `table_ins` and `table_sel`, so that I'm sure to take my sweet `id` value and execute both CTE.

This query needs to search for the value `other_key` only once, and is a "search this value" not a "check if this value not exists in the table", that is  very heavy; in Denis alternative you use `other_key` in both types of searches. In my query you "check if a value not exists" only on `id` that is a integer primary key, that, for construction, is fast.

Answer (score 0):

Minor tweak a decade late to Denis's excellent answer:

```
-- Create the table with a unique constraint
CREATE TABLE mytable (
          id serial PRIMARY KEY
,  other_key varchar NOT NULL UNIQUE
);


WITH new_row AS (
  -- Only insert when we don't find anything, avoiding a table lock if
  -- possible.
  INSERT INTO mytable ( other_key )
       SELECT 'SOMETHING'
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                  FROM mytable
                 WHERE other_key = 'SOMETHING'
              )
    RETURNING *
)
(
  -- This comes first in the UNION ALL since it'll almost certainly be
  -- in the query cache. Marginally slower for the insert case, but also
  -- marginally faster for the much more common read-only case.
  SELECT *
    FROM mytable
   WHERE other_key = 'SOMETHING'

  -- Don't check for duplicates to be removed
  UNION ALL

  -- If we reach this point in iteration, we needed to do the INSERT and
  -- lock after all.
  SELECT *
    FROM new_row

) LIMIT 1 -- Just return whatever comes first in the results and allow
          -- the query engine to cut processing short for the INSERT
          -- calculation.
;
```

The `UNION ALL` tells the planner it doesn't have to collect results for de-duplication. The `LIMIT 1` at the end allows the planner to short-circuit further processing/iteration once it knows there's an answer available.

NOTE: There is a race condition present here and in the original answer. If the entry does not already exist, the `INSERT` will fail with a unique constraint violation. The error can be suppressed with `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, but the query will return an empty set instead of the new row. This is a difficult problem because getting that info from another transaction would violate the I in ACID.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you're just trying to do this in a serializable manner, and not necessarily in one statement, you have the following simple options:

1. Use `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level (other transactions must also use it)
2. Lock the table first to prevent concurrent changes

And the following less-simple options.
If you `SELECT` first then `INSERT` if it's not there, the row can be inserted by another transaction in between. If you `INSERT` and then `SELECT` if that fails, the row can be deleted in between. One option is looping the transaction in the application until it works. Otherwise, you definitely have to do an `INSERT`, so we need the `INSERT` to also tell us the `id` of any existing row. So, insert the row, add `RETURNING` to get the `id` of the existing row. Now, you have to do `ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE` for `RETURNING` to work so you can do `SET id=mytable.id` which doesn't actually change anything. And finally, to figure out whether the row was indeed inserted in this transaction or another one, we can check the `xmin` hidden column. Putting everything together:

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (other_key)
VALUES ('SOMETHING')
ON CONFLICT (other_key) DO UPDATE SET id=mytable.id
-- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/148966/249985
RETURNING id,  xmin::text = (txid_current() % (2^32)::bigint)::text as inserted;
```

However, if the `UPDATE` happens, it [still counts as an update](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html#:%7E:text=are%20not%20considered.-,Conversely,-%2C%20a%20command%20such) for trigger purposes which may not be desired.