# SQL Update or Create Row

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, sql-update

I have a table in PostgreSQL that I need to modify, the table looks like this:

```
 name | value1 | value2 | date         
--------+-------+--------+---------
 Jonh |        |  0.15  | 2021-12-23 00:00:00
 Jonh |  0.14  |  0.76  | 2021-12-22 00:00:00
 Jonh |  0.19  |  0.87  | 2021-12-21 00:00:00
 Jonh |  0.13  |  0.11  | 2021-12-15 00:00:00
 Bob  |  0.12  |  0.23  | 2021-12-15 00:00:00
```

Having a `name`, a `date` and either `value1` or `value2`, I need to create a statement that:

1. Checks if any row with `name` and `date` exists (there is a constraint key so there can only be one row both values)
2. Inserts the value `value1` or `value2` in this row (update the row values, although initially this columns will be empty in the row).

I need to set `value1` and `value2` at different times, so I need to find a way of creating a new row or updating the current one, I was using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16128088/13071340) to create a create or update row statement, how'd you do this?

**EDIT**

Scenario 1, as input I will have the arguments:

```
name='Jonh'
value1 = 0.5
date = '2021-12-23 00:00:00'
```

In this case, a row with this name and date already exists, so it will only update the value of `value1`.
Final table:

```
 name | value1 | value2 | date         
--------+-------+--------+---------
 Jonh |  0.5   |  0.15  | 2021-12-23 00:00:00
 Jonh |  0.14  |  0.76  | 2021-12-22 00:00:00
 Jonh |  0.19  |  0.87  | 2021-12-21 00:00:00
 Jonh |  0.13  |  0.11  | 2021-12-15 00:00:00
 Bob  |  0.12  |  0.23  | 2021-12-15 00:00:00
```

Scenario 2, as input I have:

```
name='Tim'
value2 = 1
date = '2021-12-23 00:00:00'
```

Because there are no rows with this name and date, it will create a new row, assign the `value2` and set a NULL value for `value1`.
Final table:

```
 name | value1 | value2 | date         
--------+-------+--------+---------
 Tim  |        |  1     | 2021-12-23 00:00:00
 Jonh |        |  0.15  | 2021-12-23 00:00:00
 Jonh |  0.14  |  0.76  | 2021-12-22 00:00:00
 Jonh |  0.19  |  0.87  | 2021-12-21 00:00:00
 Jonh |  0.13  |  0.11  | 2021-12-15 00:00:00
 Bob  |  0.12  |  0.23  | 2021-12-15 00:00:00
```

Comment: What is the output you expect based on this sample data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updatd my question to add some expected outputs

Answer (score 5):

"Update or Insert" in SQL is commonly known as "Upsert", "Merge" or "Replace".
Check the pgsql docs:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/
and adapt its example

```
INSERT INTO customers (name, email)
VALUES('Microsoft','hotline@microsoft.com') 
ON CONFLICT (name) 
DO 
   UPDATE SET email = EXCLUDED.email || ';' || customers.email;
```

to your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INSERT ON CONFLICT syntax.

But it expects that there will be a conflict when there's a duplicate.

So for your table it needs a primary key or unique index on (name, date)

**Example**

> ```
> create table your_table (
>  name varchar(30),
>  value1 decimal(10,2),
>  value2 decimal(10,2),
>  date date
> );
>
> insert into your_table (name, value1, value2, date) values
> ('Jonh Deo', null, 0.15, '2021-12-23'), 
> ('Jonh Deo', 0.14, 0.76, '2021-12-22'), 
> ('Jonh Deo', 0.19, 0.87, '2021-12-21'), 
> ('Jonh Deo', 0.13, 0.11, '2021-12-15'), 
> ('Bob Savage', 0.12, 0.23, '2021-12-15');
> ```

> ```
> -- trying to insert a conflicting duplicate
> INSERT INTO your_table (name, value1, date)
> VALUES 
> ('Jonh Deo', 0.5, '2021-12-23')
> ON CONFLICT (name, date) 
> DO UPDATE SET value1 = EXCLUDED.value1;
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
> ```

> ```
> -- maybe it needs a PK or unique index? 
> ALTER TABLE your_table
> ADD primary key (name, date);
> ```

> ```
> -- trying to insert a conflicting duplicate again
> INSERT INTO your_table (name, value1, date)
> VALUES 
> ('Jonh Deo', 0.5, '2021-12-23')
> ON CONFLICT (name, date) 
> DO UPDATE SET value1 = EXCLUDED.value1;
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> -- now with completely original records
> INSERT INTO your_table (name, value1, value2, date)
> VALUES 
> ('Tim Bok Toh', null, 1.0, '2021-12-23'), 
> ('Tim Bok Toh',  0.6, 1.2, '2021-12-24')
> ON CONFLICT (name, date) 
> DO UPDATE SET value1 = EXCLUDED.value1
>             , value2 = EXCLUDED.value2;
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from your_table
> ```

| name | value1 | value2 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jonh Deo | 0.14 | 0.76 | 2021-12-22 |
| Jonh Deo | 0.19 | 0.87 | 2021-12-21 |
| Jonh Deo | 0.13 | 0.11 | 2021-12-15 |
| Bob Savage | 0.12 | 0.23 | 2021-12-15 |
| Jonh Deo | 0.50 | 0.15 | 2021-12-23 |
| Tim Bok Toh | *null* | 1.00 | 2021-12-23 |
| Tim Bok Toh | 0.60 | 1.20 | 2021-12-24 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=035c06bedfa930cd72ea620ef2e7bc62)*