# Single-query get_or_create in Django and Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Currently Django performs get_or_create as a series of separate two calls:

```
1. try get
2. perform create if the DoesNotExist exception was thrown
```

This can lead to `IntegrityError` exception being raised if the instance was created right after the DoesNotExist exception was thrown.

Is there any existing solution that allows to swap current django code for a postgres-specific single-query `get_or_create`? No problem if the solution only works with postgres as the db backend. Bonus points if it allows async `aget_or_create` as well.

I know this should be possible on posgres as in the accepted answer in this SO question: [Write a Postgres Get or Create SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123944/write-a-postgres-get-or-create-sql-query)
But I want to look for existing solutions before customising the calls in my code one by one.

Comment: A lot of things can result in an integrity error, this is usually why requests are wrapped in transactions, to rollback the entire transaction in case it fails.

Comment: This two operations are make into a single db transaction. so i think the conclusion is not good. You cannot get an integrity error for this reason

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950324