# Cannot SELECT reason for UNIQUE VIOLATION

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table `ContentAddressedFiles` where the combination of the columns `hash`, `size`, and `extension` are `UNIQUE`. I want to create a stored procedure that when called, will insert a new record into the table with the given values. If a record for these values already exists, I want to just return that existing record. Here's my approach:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION INIT_CAF( id_in_case_of_new UUID, _hash VARCHAR(255), _size INTEGER, _extension VARCHAR(255), _mimeType VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS "ContentAddressedFiles"
AS $$
DECLARE
  caf "ContentAddressedFiles"%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO "ContentAddressedFiles" (id, hash, size, extension, "mimeType", "createdAt", "updatedAt")
  VALUES( id_in_case_of_new, _hash, _size, _extension, _mimeType, NOW(), NOW() ) RETURNING * INTO caf;

  RETURN caf;

EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN

  SELECT * FROM "ContentAddressedFiles" INTO caf WHERE "hash" = _hash AND "size" = _size AND "extension" = _extension;

  IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'This should never happen.';
  END IF;

  RETURN caf;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, when I call the procedure from concurrent transactions, I consistently get the exception:

```
EXCEPTION: This should never happen.
```

How is this even possible? The procedure does not seem to be able to `SELECT` the reason for the failing `INSERT` before (it's not the `id` that clashes, it's just the tuple of `<hash, size, extension>`.

Comment: so you see raised exveption and null instead of expected row?.. please add output you have to the question

Comment: Yes, exactly I get the exception when I run the procedure concurrently from different transactions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722344/select-or-insert-a-row-in-one-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT or INSERT a row in one command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722344/select-or-insert-a-row-in-one-command)

Comment: I think he asks how it happens - not how to do this task easy way. I totally agree with the efficiency of link given by a_horse_with_no_name 10 mins ago, but what is the flaw with @DeX3 logic?

Comment: `id_in_case_of_new` could cause a `unique_violation` too. And I think you might misunderstood how that could work: if you supply the `id` column in an `INSERT` it will use it's value during insert (even if it's `NULL`).

Comment: no, I specifically need to generate the id on the application-side, but I can guarantee that in case of my tests, the id is not the column causing the clash (it's an UUIDv4 by the way).

Comment: Well, with [`COLUMN_NAME` / `CONSTRAINT_NAME` of `GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-EXCEPTION-DIAGNOSTICS), you can make sure.

Comment: I too wondered what is the original message? `EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN raise info '%',SQLERRM;`

Answer (score 1):

The question how to avoid the problem is answered with the comments; I'll explain here *why* PostgreSQL behaves in the observed way.

The reason is that the `INSERT` and the `SELECT` statement in the function see different *snapshots* (states) of the database, since the transaction runs with the default isolation level of `READ COMMITTED`. At that isolation level every statement gets a new database snapshot.

The explanation for the observed behaviour must be that a concurrent transaction deletes or modifies the row between the failed `INSERT` and the following `SELECT` statement, so that the row that caused the constraint violation for the `INSERT` is no longer there when the `SELECT` is run.

There are two approaches to deal with the problem:

- Choose a higher isolation level: Then both statements will see the same snapshot of the database, and the row that prevented the `INSERT` will be found by the `SELECT`, even though it has been changed in the meantime. That is no problem, it just means that the whole transaction logically takes place at the time the snapshot was taken.
- Run both statements as a single statement with a CTE, like the solution given in the comments recommends. Then they will also see the same database snapshot.

Comment: Yep, you are right, this is the most likely scenario (even if the window for race condition is tiny). At least for `VOLATILE` functions; from `STABLE`, snapshotting is different, but that category wouldn't allow `INSERT`s anyway. Maybe a great example of this snapshotting is [how the original UPSERT example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) works.