# Get or Create record with single query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-insert, database-concurrency

I have a table with column Id,column1,column2.

I wants to make sure only one record exists with column1 and column2 value (column1+column2 is unique).

If there is an already record exists with column1=v1 and column2=v2 then I wants to select the Id or insert a record with column1=v1 and column2=v2. I do not want to first select and then check and then insert since there could be a chance that 2 request came with same time with same values, both should be success but only one record should get created in DB and after that i want the Id in both request.

How to do this with single SQL ? Or is there any other better approach ?

Database : Postgres

Comment: You should have specified the database you are using. In a general way you could use where not exists (...).

Comment: Postgress database I am using

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722344/select-or-insert-a-row-in-one-command or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902

Answer (score 2):

I think the logic you are describing is a statement that attempts to insert, skips if there are duplicates, and returns the corresponding `id` in both cases (regardless of whether the insert actually happened or not).

For this to work, you need to set up a unique key on col1 and col2, so duplicates are not allowed. Your `create table` statement would look like:

```
create table mytable (
    id serial primary key,
    col1 text,
    col2 text,
    unique (col1, col2)
);
```

Then, you can write a returning insert query as follows:

```
with 
    -- query parameters
    params as (select $1 col1, $2 col2),
    -- insert, or skip if the row already exists
    ins as (
        insert into mytable (col1, col2) 
        select * from params
        on conflict (col1, col2) do nothing
    )
-- return the id
select t.id 
from mytable t
inner join params p on p.col1 = t.co1 and p.col2 = t.col2
```